# python Memory exception when write data to Disk

Tags: python, list, memory

I Have a big file about 8G to sort. and i split it into blocks（each 3G） then sort it, finally write sorted data into disk, when writting to disk, memory usage increase immediately even to 9G. i think the memory use shouldn't be so large, maybe the memeory didn't release after used, when i add del lines & gc.collect(), the memory use become normal，but the cost of time become 2 times of before, anyone knows why?

Here is my code

```

class Sorter(object):

```
def sort(self, filename='input', inp..ut_stream=None, out_filename=None, key=KEY_BY):
    sort_key = key
    def getLines(fname):
        for _ in open(fname, 'r'):
            yield (sort_key(_), _)
    st = time.time()
    splitter = FileSplitter(filename)
    if input_stream:
        splitter.split(self.block_size, input_stream=input_stream, key=sort_key, buffer_size=self.buffer_size)
    else:
        splitter.split(self.block_size, key=sort_key, buffer_size=self.buffer_size)
        # splitter.split(self.block_size, sort_key, self.buffer_size)
    print >> sys.stderr, 'sort', time.time() - st
    st = time.time()
    filelist = map(getLines, splitter.get_block_filenames())
    r = heapq.merge(*filelist)
    if not out_filename:
        f = open(filename + '.out', 'w')
    else:
        f = open(out_filename, 'w')
    map(lambda _: f.write(_[1]), r)
    print >> sys.stderr, 'merge', time.time() - st
    splitter.cleanup()
```

class FileSplitter(object):

```
BLOCK_FILENAME_FORMAT = 'block_{0}.dat'

def __init__(self, filename):
    self.filename = filename
    self.block_filenames = []

def write_block(self, data, block_number, buffer_size):
    filename = self.BLOCK_FILENAME_FORMAT.format(block_number)
    file = open(filename, 'w', buffer_size)
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    self.block_filenames.append(filename)

def get_block_filenames(self):
    return self.block_filenames

def split(self, block_size, input_stream=None, key=None, buffer_size=0):
    sort_key = key
    if not input_stream:
        file = open(self.filename, 'r', buffer_size)
    else:
        file = input_stream
    i = 0
    while True:
        lines = file.readlines(block_size)
        if lines == []:
            break
        if sort_key is None:
            lines.sort()
        else:
            lines.sort(key=sort_key)
        self.write_block(''.join(lines), i, buffer_size=buffer_size)
        i += 1

def cleanup(self):
    map(lambda f: os.remove(f), self.block_filenames)
```

```

Here is the usage of memory in each line:

```

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
21 6817.344 MiB 18170.859 MiB       @profile
22                                 def write_block(self, data, block_number, buffer_size):
23 6817.344 MiB -1652.430 MiB           filename = self.BLOCK_FILENAME_FORMAT.format(block_number)
24 6817.344 MiB -1652.430 MiB           file = open(filename, 'w', buffer_size)
25 6817.344 MiB -1652.430 MiB           file.write(data)
26 6817.344 MiB -1652.430 MiB           file.close()
27 6817.344 MiB -1652.430 MiB           self.block_filenames.append(filename)
```

Filename: ../../isorter.py

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
32   21.504 MiB   21.504 MiB       @profile
33                                 def split(self, block_size, input_stream=None, key=None, buffer_size=0):
36   21.504 MiB    0.000 MiB           sort_key = key
37   21.504 MiB    0.000 MiB           if not input_stream:
38                                         file = open(self.filename, 'r', buffer_size)
39                                     else:
40   21.504 MiB    0.000 MiB               file = input_stream
41   21.504 MiB    0.000 MiB           i = 0

43 5164.914 MiB    0.000 MiB           while True:
44 5164.801 MiB 4979.527 MiB               lines = file.readlines(block_size)
45 5164.801 MiB -157.926 MiB               if lines == []:
46 5006.875 MiB -157.926 MiB                   break
47 5164.801 MiB    0.000 MiB               if sort_key is None:
48                                             lines.sort()
49                                         else:
50 5164.914 MiB    5.844 MiB                   lines.sort(key=sort_key)
51 5164.914 MiB 12020.230 MiB               self.write_block(''.join(lines), i, buffer_size=buffer_size)
52 5164.914 MiB    0.000 MiB               i += 1
53 5006.879 MiB    0.004 MiB           print
```

Filename: ../../isorter.py

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
56 5006.906 MiB 5006.906 MiB       @profile
57                                 def cleanup(self):
58 5006.906 MiB    0.000 MiB           map(lambda f: os.remove(f), self.block_filenames)
```

Filename: ../../isorter.py

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
61 5006.898 MiB 5006.898 MiB   @profile
62                             def merge(filelist):
63 5006.898 MiB    0.000 MiB       return heapq.merge(*filelist)
```

Filename: ../../isorter.py

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
71   21.340 MiB   21.340 MiB       @profile
72                                 def sort(self, filename='input', input_stream=None, out_filename=None, key=KEY_BY):
76   21.504 MiB    0.000 MiB           sort_key = key
77 5006.902 MiB    0.000 MiB           def getLines(fname):
78 5006.918 MiB -189.023 MiB               for _ in open(fname, 'r'):
79 5006.918 MiB -378.035 MiB                   yield (sort_key(_), _)
80   21.504 MiB    0.000 MiB           st = time.time()
83   21.504 MiB    0.000 MiB           splitter = FileSplitter(filename)
84   21.504 MiB    0.000 MiB           if input_stream:
85 5006.879 MiB 5006.879 MiB               splitter.split(self.block_size, input_stream=input_stream, key=sort_key, buffer_size=self.buffer_size)
86                                     else:
87                                         splitter.split(self.block_size, key=sort_key, buffer_size=self.buffer_size)
88 5006.898 MiB    0.020 MiB           print >> sys.stderr, 'sort', time.time() - st
90 5006.898 MiB    0.000 MiB           st = time.time()
91 5006.898 MiB    0.000 MiB           filelist = map(getLines, splitter.get_block_filenames())
94 5006.898 MiB 5006.898 MiB           r = merge(filelist)
96 5006.898 MiB    0.000 MiB           if not out_filename:
97                                         f = open(filename + '.out', 'w')
98                                     else:
99 5006.898 MiB    0.000 MiB               f = open(out_filename, 'w')
```

100 5006.918 MiB -378.051 MiB           map(lambda *: f.write(*[1]), r)
   101 5006.906 MiB   -0.012 MiB           print >> sys.stderr, 'merge', time.time() - st
   102 5006.906 MiB 5006.906 MiB           splitter.cleanup()

```

Comment: How do you use the classes? Also important parts of `Sorter` seem to be missing.

Comment: thanks, i'll add the full file

Comment: > CMD: cat data |python xxxxx

```
import sys
import Sorter

def main():
    sorter = Sorter(3072*1024*1024)
    sorter.sort(filename='input', input_stream=sys.stdin, out_filename='input.sorted', key=getKeyOfDeviceid)

```@KlausD. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy array instead of python's list. Numpy array use less memory than list.
for example if your code is :

```
x = [] 
for a in mylist: 
    x.append(a)
```

replace that with :

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([])
for a in mylist:
    x = np.append(x,a)
```

Comment: i want to find the reason, why  i call self.write_block(''.join(lines)),  the use of memory will increase to 2 times

Comment: maybe is the object file doesn't released after use